# Im trying to create a pop-up box type when hovering over specific text, but the text only hides and does not show further

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to create a pop-up box that will pop-up when you hover over text. The text disappears but it does not reappear when you hover your mouse over it. Any improvements that can be made to the code below?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("clo-t").hide();

  $("clo").hover(function(){
    $("clo-t").show();,
    $("clo-t").hide();
  });

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mouseout` and `mouseover` instead

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".clo").mouseover(() => {
    $(".clo-t").show();
  }).mouseout(t => {
    if (!$(t.target).hasClass("clo-t"))
      $(".clo-t").hide();
  })
})
```